# Change customView of Tab when selected

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-tablayout

[image]I want to change image of tab Price when selected.
When it is pressed first time, it displays products according to price in ascending order ,when  same tab is pressed again It displays products according to price in descending Order.
I am unable to change image of tab to display the order.
I am using customView for my 3rd tab as it contains image aligned right to text,

Below is my code:

**price_tab.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/price"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:src="@drawable/lth" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**ProductActivity.java**

```
tablayout.addTab(tablayout.newTab().setText(getText(R.string.popular)), 0);
        tablayout.addTab(tablayout.newTab().setText(getText(R.string.new_tag)), 1);
        tablayout.addTab(tablayout.newTab().setText(getText(R.string.price)), 2);
        View mCustomView = LayoutInflater.from(ProductActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.price_tab, null);
        mImageViewCustom = (ImageView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        tablayout.getTabAt(2).setCustomView(mCustomView);
        tablayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(Tab tab) {

                if (tab.getText().equals(getString(R.string.new_tag))) {
                    sort = 0;
                    page = 1;
                    isLastPage = false;
                    productList.clear();
                    productListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    getProducts();


                } else if (tab.getText().equals(getString(R.string.price))) {
                    if (sort != 2) {
                        sort = 2;

                        mImageViewCustom.setImageResource(R.drawable.lth);
                    } else {
                        sort = 3;
                        mImageViewCustom.setImageResource(R.drawable.htl);
                    }
                    page = 1;
                    isLastPage = false;
                    productList.clear();
                    productListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    getProducts();

                } else if (tab.getText().equals(getString(R.string.popular))) {
                    sort = 1;


                    page = 1;
                    isLastPage = false;
                    productList.clear();
                    productListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    getProducts();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(Tab tab) {

                if (tab.getText().equals("Price")) {
                    if (sort == 2) {
                        sort = 3;
                    } else
                        sort = 2;
                    page = 1;
                    isLastPage = false;
                    productList.clear();
                    productListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    getProducts();
                }
            }


        });

        getProducts();
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `onTabReselcted()`, try below code:

```
@Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            if (tab.getText().toString().equals("Price")) {
                if (sort == 2) {
                    sort = 3;
                } else
                    sort = 2;
                page = 1;
                isLastPage = false;
                productList.clear();
                productListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                //change tab icon
                View view = tab.getCustomView();
                if (view != null) {
                   ImageView icon = view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
                   icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_image_resource);
                }      

                getProducts();
            }
        }
```

Depending on your `sort` logic you can change the icon from increasing to decreasing and vice versa

Answer (score 1):

By using this you can customize any tab you want according to the current position of the tab.

```
private TabLayout tabs;
tabs = view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
```

.

```
 tabs.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {


                    if (tab.getPosition()==your tab position){
                        tabs.setTabTextColors(Color.parseColor("#fdb827"), Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
                        tabs.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));

                    }else {
                        tabs.setTabTextColors(Color.parseColor("#fdb827"), Color.parseColor("#F57F17"));
                        tabs.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(Color.parseColor("#fdb827"));
                    }



                }

                @Override
                public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                }
                @Override
                public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                }
            });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I want to change the tab Image which is next to Price Text.When Price Tab is pressed,image  next to it shoud toggle from increasing to decreasing or decreasing to increasing